# What is the best way of handling long lines of variables definition

Tags: variables, actionscript-3

I have 197 variables and definition part takes too much lines. All of them used in various functions and modified by.

Here are some part of the code itself yet not the whole code (30k limit of the page). I am asking a general programming method/solution for that specific situation for specific "language", ActionScript3.

What is the correct way of managing similar situation? Is there any methods to reduce line numbers?

This is the source file if anyone wants to look at it: https://github.com/MA62CNB/ergeneriver/blob/master/GameL.as

```
package 
{
    import GameL.*;
    import caurina.transitions.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.ui.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class GameL extends Sprite
    {
        var sfxChannel:SoundChannel;
        var bgmChannel:SoundChannel;
        var bgmLoopChannel:SoundChannel;
        var playerMove:cocuk_hareket;
        var rightChoice:dogru_nesne;
        var introMusic:giris_icin_tam_muzik;
        var bgmLoop:oyun_ici_loop_muzik;
        var sfxVarious:secimler;
        var success:tebrikler;
        var success2:tebrikler2;
        var wrongChoice:yanlis_nesne;
        const MAIN_VOLUME:Number = 0.7;
        const INGAME_VOLUME:Number = 0.2;
        var soundStr:String;
        var sndTrans:SoundTransform;
        var bgmMute:Boolean = false;
        const ZERO:int = 3;
        var htpScreen:MainHelp;
        var ingameHelp:GameInfomc;
        var titleBg:Harita;
        var yildiz1:Yildiz1;
        var yildiz2:Yildiz2;
        var yildiz3:Yildiz3;
        var yildizSon:Finale;
        var randomPoint:RandomPlus;
        var randomPoint2:RandomPlus;
        var toplam:Array;
        var char:int = -1;
        var currentRoadLine:int = 3;
        var index1:int = 0;
        var index2:int = 0;
        var index3:int = 0;
        var info:Info;
        var cont1:MovieClip;
        var cont2:MovieClip;
        var cont3:MovieClip;
        var cont4:MovieClip;
        var nehirBg:Blm1;
        var bolumNo:BolumNo;
        var kopruImg:Kopru;
        var yesil:Yesil;
        var sari:Sari;
        var pembe:Pembe;
        var bot:Bot;
        var deter:Deter;
        var bidon:Bidon;
        var kutu:Kutu;
        var lastik:Lastik;
        var cips:Cips;
        var pet:Pet;
        var konserve:Konserve;
        var balik:Balik;
        var ordek:Ordek;
        var kurbaga:Kurbaga;
        var oyuncu:MovieClip;
        var canImg:Health;
        var point:Points;
        var itemSpeed:Object;
        var score:Object;
        var lives:Object;
        var levelNo:Object;
        var completed:int;
        var endInterval:Timer;
        var interval2:Timer;
        var allLives:int = 4;
        var animalArray:Array;
        var trashArray:Array;
        var pos1:Array;
        var posArray:Array;
        var pos3:Array;
        var posYs:Array;
        var finalBg:Kirli;
        var pops:Pops;
        var oyunSonu:OyunSon;
        var gunes:Sun;
        var copler:Copler;
        var pompa:Pompa;
        var trak1:Traktor;
        var trak2:Traktor;
        var trak3:Traktor;
        var trak4:Traktor;
        var panel:Panel;
        var ormanAlan:OrmanAlan;
        var bacaAlan:BacaAlan;
        var turbinAlan:TurbinAlan;
        var aritmaAlan:AritmaAlan;
        var bacaIcon:baca_ikon;
        var ormanIcon:camlar_ikon;
        var turbinIcon:turbin_ikon;
        var aritmaIcon:aritma_ikon;
        var pompaIcon:pompa_ikon;
        var trkatorIcon:traktor_ikon;
        var coplerIcon:copler_ikon;
        var trackIndex:int;
        var counter:int = 0;
        var traktorCounter:int = 0;
        var aritmaFlag:Boolean = false;
        var how:HowPlay;
        var howLast:HowLast;
        var restart_bg:Restart;
        var restart_btn:RButton;
        var nextBg:Interscreen;
        var nextBtn:Next;
        var once:Boolean = true;

        public function GameL()
        {
            this.sfxChannel = new SoundChannel();
            this.bgmChannel = new SoundChannel();
            this.bgmLoopChannel = new SoundChannel();
            this.playerMove = new cocuk_hareket();
            this.rightChoice = new dogru_nesne();
            this.introMusic = new giris_icin_tam_muzik();
            this.bgmLoop = new oyun_ici_loop_muzik();
            this.sfxVarious = new secimler();
            this.success = new tebrikler();
            this.success2 = new tebrikler2();
            this.wrongChoice = new yanlis_nesne();
            this.sndTrans = new SoundTransform();
            this.htpScreen = new MainHelp();
            this.ingameHelp = new GameInfomc();
            this.titleBg = new Harita();
            this.yildiz1 = new Yildiz1();
            this.yildiz2 = new Yildiz2();
            this.yildiz3 = new Yildiz3();
            this.yildizSon = new Finale();
            this.randomPoint = new RandomPlus(0, 3);
            this.randomPoint2 = new RandomPlus(0, 2);
            this.toplam = new Array();
            this.info = new Info();
            this.nehirBg = new Blm1();
            this.bolumNo = new BolumNo();
            this.kopruImg = new Kopru();
            this.yesil = new Yesil();
            this.sari = new Sari();
            this.pembe = new Pembe();
            this.bot = new Bot();
            this.deter = new Deter();
            this.bidon = new Bidon();
            this.kutu = new Kutu();
            this.lastik = new Lastik();
            this.cips = new Cips();
            this.pet = new Pet();
            this.konserve = new Konserve();
            this.balik = new Balik();
            this.ordek = new Ordek();
            this.kurbaga = new Kurbaga();
            this.oyuncu = new MovieClip();
            this.canImg = new Health();
            this.point = new Points();
            this.endInterval = new Timer(500, 1);
            this.interval2 = new Timer(250, 1);
            this.trashArray = new Array();
            this.pos1 = [395, 595, 795];
            this.posArray = [296, 496, 696, 896];
            this.pos3 = [300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900];
            this.posYs = [-110, -210, -310];
            this.copler = new Copler();
            this.pompa = new Pompa();
            this.trak1 = new Traktor();
            this.trak2 = new Traktor();
            this.trak3 = new Traktor();
            this.trak4 = new Traktor();
            this.ormanAlan = new OrmanAlan();
            this.bacaAlan = new BacaAlan();
            this.turbinAlan = new TurbinAlan();
            this.aritmaAlan = new AritmaAlan();
            this.bacaIcon = new baca_ikon();
            this.ormanIcon = new camlar_ikon();
            this.turbinIcon = new turbin_ikon();
            this.aritmaIcon = new aritma_ikon();
            this.pompaIcon = new pompa_ikon();
            this.trkatorIcon = new traktor_ikon();
            this.coplerIcon = new copler_ikon();
            this.how = new HowPlay();
            this.howLast = new HowLast();
            this.restart_bg = new Restart();
            this.restart_btn = new RButton();
            this.nextBg = new Interscreen();
            this.nextBtn = new Next();
            this.init(0);
            this.levelNo = 1;
            this.completed = 0;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function init(addChild:int) : void
        {
            switch(addChild)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    this.InitLobi();
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    this.completed = 0;
                    this.levelNo = 1;
                    this.itemSpeed = 12;
                    this.score = 0;
                    this.nehirBg.kirlinehirmc.alpha = 0.5;
                    this.point.texts.text = "0";
                    this.lives = 3;
                    this.canImg.gotoAndStop(1);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    this.currentRoadLine = this.ZERO;
                    this.itemSpeed = 15;
                    this.score = 0;
                    this.nehirBg.kirlinehirmc.alpha = 0.5;
                    this.point.texts.text = "0";
                    this.lives = 3;
                    this.canImg.gotoAndStop(1);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    this.currentRoadLine = this.ZERO;
                    this.itemSpeed = 16;
                    this.score = 0;
                    this.nehirBg.kirlinehirmc.alpha = 0.5;
                    this.point.texts.text = "0";
                    this.lives = 3;
                    this.canImg.gotoAndStop(1);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    this.BeginLast();
                    break;
                }
                case -1:
                {
                    addChild(this.restart_bg);
                    this.restart_bg.cacheAsBitmap = true;
                    addChild(this.restart_btn);
                    this.restart_bg.x = 0;
                    this.restart_bg.y = 0;
                    this.restart_btn.x = 352.5;
                    this.restart_btn.y = 512.5;
                    this.restart_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.DoRestart, false, 0, true);
                    this.restart_btn.buttonMode = true;
                    this.canImg.gotoAndStop(4);
                    this.score = 0;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function InitLobi()
        {
            this.sndTrans.volume = this.MAIN_VOLUME;
            addChild(this.titleBg);
            if (this.bgmMute == false)
            {
                this.titleBg.ses_kontrol.gotoAndStop(1);
                SoundMixer.stopAll();
                this.bgmLoopChannel.stop();
                this.bgmChannel.stop();
                this.bgmChannel = this.introMusic.play(0, 1, this.sndTrans);
                this.bgmChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, this.IsSoundFinished);
            }
            else
            {
                this.titleBg.ses_kontrol.gotoAndStop(2);
                this.bgmMute = false;
            }
            this.titleBg.ses_kontrol.buttonMode = true;
            this.titleBg.ses_kontrol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.BgmControl);
            this.soundStr = "introMusic";
            this.titleBg.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.titleBg.helpb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.DisplayHtp);
            this.titleBg.helpb.buttonMode = true;
            this.titleBg.y2mc.visible = true;
            this.titleBg.y3mc.visible = true;
            this.titleBg.y4mc.visible = true;
            addChild(this.yildiz1);
            addChild(this.yildiz2);
            addChild(this.yildiz3);
            addChild(this.yildizSon);
            this.yildiz2.visible = false;
            this.yildiz3.visible = false;
            this.yildizSon.visible = false;
            this.yildiz1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.FirstStage);
            this.yildiz1.buttonMode = true;
            this.YildizLoaderHandler();
            this.titleBg.x = 0;
            this.titleBg.y = 0;
            this.yildiz1.x = 215.8;
            this.yildiz1.y = 158.9;
            this.yildiz2.x = 132.45;
            this.yildiz2.y = 411.5;
            this.yildiz3.x = 463.25;
            this.yildiz3.y = 282.6;
            this.yildizSon.x = 734.55;
            this.yildizSon.y = 199.6;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function InitMain()
        {
            var _loc_3:uint = 0;
            var _loc_4:uint = 0;
            var _loc_5:uint = 0;
            var _loc_6:OyunK = null;
            var _loc_7:OyunE = null;
            this.sndTrans.volume = this.INGAME_VOLUME;
            this.cont1 = new MovieClip();
            this.cont2 = new MovieClip();
            this.cont3 = new MovieClip();
            this.cont1.addChild(this.nehirBg);
            this.cont1.addChild(this.bolumNo);
            this.cont1.addChild(this.canImg);
            this.cont1.addChild(this.point);
            if (this.bgmMute == false)
            {
                this.point.ses_cont.gotoAndStop(1);
                this.bgmChannel.stop();
                this.bgmLoopChannel.stop();
                this.bgmLoopChannel = this.bgmLoop.play(0, 1, this.sndTrans);
                this.bgmLoopChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, this.IsSoundFinished);
            }
            else
            {
                this.point.ses_cont.gotoAndStop(2);
                this.bgmMute = false;
            }
            this.point.ses_cont.buttonMode = true;
            this.point.ses_cont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.BgmControl);
            this.soundStr = "bgmLoop";
            this.endInterval.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, this.IntervalHandler);
            this.nehirBg.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.bolumNo.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.canImg.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.point.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.MainScenes);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.KeyMoves);
            this.point.play_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.PauseGame);
            this.point.lobi_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.GoLobi);
            this.point.yardim_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.ShowIngameHelp);
            this.point.play_b.buttonMode = true;
            this.point.lobi_b.buttonMode = true;
            this.point.yardim_b.buttonMode = true;
            this.animalArray = [this.balik, this.kurbaga, this.ordek];
            this.trashArray = [this.bidon, this.bot, this.cips, this.deter, this.konserve, this.kutu, this.lastik, this.pet, this.pembe, this.sari, this.yesil];
            var _loc_1:uint = 0;
            while (_loc_1++ < 3)
            {

                this.animalArray[_loc_1].x = this.posArray[this.randomPoint.getNum()];
                this.animalArray[_loc_1].y = this.posYs[this.randomPoint2.getNum()];
                addChild(this.cont1);
                this.cont1.addChild(this.animalArray[_loc_1]);
            }
            var _loc_2:uint = 0;
            while (_loc_2++ < 11)
            {

                this.trashArray[_loc_2].x = this.pos1[this.randomPoint2.getNum()];
                this.trashArray[_loc_2].y = -150;
                addChild(this.cont2);
                this.cont2.addChild(this.trashArray[_loc_2]);
            }
            addChild(this.cont3);
            this.cont3.addChild(this.kopruImg);
            if (this.levelNo == 1)
            {
                _loc_3 = 0;
                while (_loc_3++ < 11)
                {

                    this.toplam[_loc_3] = 1;
                }
            }
            if (this.levelNo == 2)
            {
                _loc_4 = 0;
                while (_loc_4++ < 11)
                {

                    this.toplam[_loc_4] = 1;
                }
            }
            if (this.levelNo == 3)
            {
                _loc_5 = 0;
                while (_loc_5++ < 11)
                {

                    this.toplam[_loc_5] = 1;
                }
            }
            if (this.char == 1)
            {
                _loc_6 = new OyunK();
                this.oyuncu = _loc_6;
            }
            if (this.char == 0)
            {
                _loc_7 = new OyunE();
                this.oyuncu = _loc_7;
            }
            this.oyuncu.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.nehirBg.x = 0;
            this.nehirBg.y = 0;
            this.kopruImg.y = 588;
            this.bolumNo.x = 43.2;
            this.bolumNo.y = 22.8;
            this.oyuncu.x = 600;
            this.oyuncu.y = 450;
            this.cont3.addChild(this.oyuncu);
            this.canImg.x = 55.9;
            this.canImg.y = 134;
            this.point.x = stage.stageWidth - (this.point.width + this.point.width / 8);
            this.point.y = 25;
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.MainScenes, false, 0, true);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function MainScenes(event:Event)
        {
            this.bolumNo.blm_num.text = String(this.levelNo);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.KeyMoves);
            var _loc_2:uint = 0;
            while (_loc_2++ < this.toplam.length)
            {

                if (this.toplam[_loc_2] < 0)
                {
                    this.toplam[_loc_2] = 0;
                }
            }
            this.point.txt0.text = String(this.toplam[0]);
            this.point.txt1.text = String(this.toplam[1]);
            this.point.txt2.text = String(this.toplam[2]);
            this.point.txt3.text = String(this.toplam[3]);
            this.point.txt4.text = String(this.toplam[4]);
            this.point.txt5.text = String(this.toplam[5]);
            this.point.txt6.text = String(this.toplam[6]);
            this.point.txt7.text = String(this.toplam[7]);
            this.point.txt8.text = String(this.toplam[8] + this.toplam[9] + this.toplam[10]);
            if (!this.Puanlama(this.toplam))
            {
                if (this.oyuncu.x <= this.pos3[0])
                {
                    this.oyuncu.x = this.pos3[0];
                }
                else if (this.oyuncu.x >= this.pos3[this.pos3.length--])
                {
                    this.oyuncu.x = this.pos3[this.pos3.length--];
                }
                if (this.animalArray != null)
                {
                    if (this.animalArray[0].y > stage.stageHeight)
                    {
                        this.animalArray[0].x = this.posArray[this.randomPoint.getNum()];
                        this.animalArray[0].y = -150;
                        var _loc_3:String = this;
                        _loc_3.index1 = this.index1++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (this.animalArray[0].hitTestObject(this.oyuncu.suzgec_alan_MC))
                        {
                            var _loc_3:String = this;
                            _loc_3.lives = this.lives--;
                            this.nehirBg.nega.gotoAndPlay(2);
                            this.canImg.gotoAndStop(this.allLives - this.lives);
                            this.score = this.score - 100;
                            this.sfxChannel.stop();
                            this.sfxChannel = this.wrongChoice.play();
                            this.point.texts.text = String(this.score);
                            this.animalArray[0].x = this.posArray[this.randomPoint.getNum()];
                            this.animalArray[0].y = -150;
                        }
                        this.animalArray[0].y = this.animalArray[0].y + this.itemSpeed;
                    }
                }
                if (this.levelNo > 1 && this.animalArray != null)
                {
                    if (this.animalArray[1].y > stage.stageHeight)
                    {
                        this.animalArray[1].x = this.posArray[this.randomPoint.getNum()];
                        this.animalArray[1].y = -150;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (this.animalArray[1].hitTestObject(this.oyuncu.suzgec_alan_MC))
                        {
                            var _loc_3:String = this;
                            _loc_3.lives = this.lives--;
                            this.nehirBg.nega.gotoAndPlay(2);
                            this.canImg.gotoAndStop(this.allLives - this.lives);
                            this.score = this.score - 100;
                            this.sfxChannel.stop();
                            this.sfxChannel = this.wrongChoice.play();
                            this.point.texts.text = String(this.score);
                            this.animalArray[1].x = this.posArray[this.randomPoint.getNum()];
                            this.animalArray[1].y = -150;
                        }
                        this.animalArray[1].y = this.animalArray[1].y + this.itemSpeed;
                    }
                }
                if (this.levelNo > 2 && this.animalArray != null)
                {
                    if (this.animalArray[2].y > stage.stageHeight)
                    {
                        this.animalArray[2].x = this.posArray[this.randomPoint.getNum()];
                        this.animalArray[2].y = -150;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (this.animalArray[2].hitTestObject(this.oyuncu.suzgec_alan_MC))
                        {
                            var _loc_3:String = this;
                            _loc_3.lives = this.lives--;
                            this.nehirBg.nega.gotoAndPlay(2);
                            this.canImg.gotoAndStop(this.allLives - this.lives);
                            this.score = this.score - 100;
                            this.sfxChannel.stop();
                            this.sfxChannel = this.wrongChoice.play();
                            this.point.texts.text = String(this.score);
                            this.animalArray[2].x = this.posArray[this.randomPoint.getNum()];
                            this.animalArray[2].y = -150;
                        }
                        this.animalArray[2].y = this.animalArray[2].y + this.itemSpeed;
                    }
                }
                if (this.trashArray != null && this.index3 < this.trashArray.length)
                {
                    if (this.trashArray[this.index3].y > stage.stageHeight)
                    {
                        var _loc_3:String = this;
                        _loc_3.lives = this.lives--;
                        this.nehirBg.nega.gotoAndPlay(2);
                        this.canImg.gotoAndStop(this.allLives - this.lives);
                        this.score = this.score - 100;
                        this.sfxChannel.stop();
                        this.sfxChannel = this.wrongChoice.play();
                        this.point.texts.text = String(this.score);
                        this.trashArray[this.index3].x = this.pos1[this.randomPoint2.getNum()];
                        this.trashArray[this.index3].y = -150;
                        var _loc_3:String = this;
                        _loc_3.index3 = this.index3++;
                        if (this.index3 >= this.trashArray.length)
                        {
                            this.index3 = 0;
                            this.trashArray[this.index1].x = this.pos1[this.randomPoint2.getNum()];
                            this.trashArray[this.index1].y = -150;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (this.trashArray[this.index3].hitTestObject(this.oyuncu.suzgec_alan_MC))
                        {
                            this.score = this.score + 100;
                            this.nehirBg.plus.gotoAndPlay(2);
                            this.sfxChannel.stop();
                            this.sfxChannel = this.rightChoice.play();
                            this.point.texts.text = String(this.score);
                            this.trashArray[this.index3].x = this.pos1[this.randomPoint2.getNum()];
                            this.trashArray[this.index3].y = -150;
                            var _loc_3:* = this.toplam;
                            var _loc_4:* = this.index3;
                            _loc_3[_loc_4] = this.toplam[this.index3]--;
                            var _loc_3:String = this;
                            _loc_3.index3 = this.index3++;
                            if (this.index3 >= this.trashArray.length)
                            {
                                this.index3 = 0;
                                this.trashArray[this.index3].x = this.pos1[this.randomPoint2.getNum()];
                                this.trashArray[this.index3].y = -150;
                            }
                            if (this.nehirBg.kirlinehirmc.alpha > 0)
                            {
                                this.nehirBg.kirlinehirmc.alpha = this.nehirBg.kirlinehirmc.alpha - 0.05;
                            }
                        }
                        this.trashArray[this.index3].y = this.trashArray[this.index3].y + this.itemSpeed;
                    }
                }
                if (this.lives < 1)
                {
                    this.canImg.gotoAndStop(5);
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.MainScenes);
                    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.KeyMoves);
                    this.endInterval.start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.MainScenes);
                stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.KeyMoves);
                this.endInterval.start();
                this.score = 0;
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function FirstStage(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            this.sfxChannel.stop();
            this.sfxChannel = this.sfxVarious.play();
            this.init(1);
            addChild(this.info);
            this.info.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.info.gotoAndStop(1);
            this.info.ileriok.gotoAndStop(1);
            this.info.x = 0;
            this.info.y = 0;
            this.info.ileriok.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.NextPage);
            this.info.ileriok.buttonMode = true;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function KeyMoves(event:KeyboardEvent) : void
        {
            var _loc_2:* = event.keyCode;
            var _loc_3:* = 1.3 - 0.5;
            this.sfxChannel.stop();
            this.sfxChannel = this.playerMove.play();
            switch(_loc_2)
            {
                case Keyboard.LEFT:
                {
                    if (this.currentRoadLine > 0)
                    {
                        var _loc_4:String = this;
                        _loc_4.currentRoadLine = this.currentRoadLine--;
                        Tweener.addTween(this.oyuncu, {x:this.pos3[this.currentRoadLine], time:_loc_3});
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                {
                    if (this.currentRoadLine < this.pos3.length)
                    {
                        if (this.currentRoadLine != this.pos3.length--)
                        {
                            var _loc_4:String = this;
                            _loc_4.currentRoadLine = this.currentRoadLine++;
                        }
                        Tweener.addTween(this.oyuncu, {x:this.pos3[this.currentRoadLine], time:_loc_3});
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        private function Puanlama(txt2:Array) : Boolean
        {
            var _loc_2:Boolean = false;
            var _loc_3:int = 0;
            var _loc_4:uint = 0;
            while (_loc_4++ < txt2.length)
            {

                if (txt2[_loc_4] == 0 || txt2[_loc_4] < 0)
                {
                    _loc_3++;
                }
            }
            if (_loc_3 == txt2.length)
            {
                _loc_2 = true;
            }
            return _loc_2;
        }// end function

        private function BeginLast()
        {
            addChild(this.how);
            this.how.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.how.gotoAndStop(1);
            this.how.start_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.FinalScene);
            this.how.start_b.buttonMode = true;
            this.how.start_b.gotoAndStop(1);
            return;
        }// end function

        private function StartGame(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            this.InitMain();
            return;
        }// end function

        private function ReturnGame(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.MainScenes);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.KeyMoves);
            this.ingameHelp.visible = false;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function PauseGame(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            this.point.play_b.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.ResumeGame);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.MainScenes);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.KeyMoves);
            this.point.play_b.gotoAndStop(2);
            this.point.play_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.ResumeGame);
            this.point.play_b.buttonMode = true;
            return;
        }// end function

        private function ResumeGame(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            this.point.play_b.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.PauseGame);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.MainScenes);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.KeyMoves);
            this.point.play_b.gotoAndStop(1);
            this.point.play_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.PauseGame);
            this.point.play_b.buttonMode = true;
            return;
        }// end function
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to impove your Question? Two lines of text is not enough info to get a good answer. For example are these mysterious 300 vars of the same data type? Show an example of 3 vars (or more) and show us how their definition takes too much lines... Maybe then we can give you some ideas to reduce...

Comment: I say review your variables if there are any unused or similar ones that can be combined into an array, or are somehow interdependent to be refactored into a separate class. Otherwise none, if you need all those 300 in your code, then you need to declare all of them.

Comment: Oh my, 1700 lines of code and just 1 class???? First, you need to break your main class into many smaller classes, easier to manage and debug. I didn't bother to read your code, it just way tooo long.

Comment: @DTDT You cannot define more than one class under a package per file. Get your facts right.

Comment: @coner, if you are a programmer/developer, even a beginner,  you know what I mean. I didn't tell you to break the main class into many smaller classes and place them all in one file. By the way, I can tell you didn't write that code, you decompile someone's file and take that code.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code and the main problem is the code isn't optimized. The variable are a reflection or symptom of the way the code is. It's not wrong, you're just at that stage in learning how to program where you're doing everything literally. If you clear up your code, the need for a huge chunk of your variables will disappear.

You're using literal naming for your variables. When you start optimizing your code you'll see how you don't want to name things literally.

For example, I can't see what's going on but it looks like a bacaIcon and ormaIcon are probably the same in everything you do to them in the code except they're attached to two different objects.

The best thing to do to find optimization issues in your code is to simply look for repetition. Ideally, you really don't see repetition in optimized code. Don't read the code and try to process it, simply look at the code on the page and look for chunks of code that look similar.

Here are a couple examples from your code to show what I'm talking about:

First, an simple example, look at the repetition in these:

```
        this.ormanIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.StartDragn);
        this.ormanIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.StopDragn);
        this.ormanIcon.buttonMode = true;
        this.bacaIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.StartDragn);
        this.bacaIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.StopDragn);
        this.bacaIcon.buttonMode = true;
        this.turbinIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.StartDragn);
        this.turbinIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.StopDragn);
        this.turbinIcon.buttonMode = true;
        this.aritmaIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.StartDragn);
        this.aritmaIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.StopDragn);
        this.aritmaIcon.buttonMode = true;
```

Simply looking at the code you see all those words repeating. You don't have to know what the code is doing to know that repetition is wrong. So look for what is actually changing in the repetition, in this case the target of the action, the icons, turn the changing part into a variable, the rest into a function, and make a loop.

Here's another example that's bigger but the same. You have many of these, they should be a function

```
if (this.copler.hitTestObject(this.panel.kp.area))
            {
                this.sfxChannel.stop();
                this.sfxChannel = this.rightChoice.play();
                this.copler.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.StartDragn);
                this.copler.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.StopDragn);
                removeChild(this.copler);
                addChild(this.coplerIcon);
                addChild(this.pops);
                this.finalBg.kirlihava.alpha = this.finalBg.kirlihava.alpha - 0.13;
                this.finalBg.kirlitoprak.alpha = this.finalBg.kirlitoprak.alpha - 0.5;
                this.finalBg.cicekmc.visible = true;
                this.gunes.alpha = this.gunes.alpha + 0.16;
                var _loc_3:String = this;
                _loc_3.counter = this.counter++;
                this.pops.pop_cop.visible = true;
                this.pops.bg.visible = true;
                this.pops.pop_cop.popx.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.PopTicker);
                this.pops.pop_cop.popx.buttonMode = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.sfxChannel.stop();
                this.sfxChannel = this.wrongChoice.play();
                this.copler.x = 863.65;
                this.copler.y = 521.6;
            }
        }
        if (event.target == this.pompa)
        {
            this.pompa.stopDrag();
            if (this.pompa.hitTestObject(this.panel.kp.area))
            {
                this.sfxChannel.stop();
                this.sfxChannel = this.rightChoice.play();
                this.pompa.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.StartDragn);
                this.pompa.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.StopDragn);
                removeChild(this.pompa);
                addChild(this.pompaIcon);
                addChild(this.pops);
                this.finalBg.kirlihava.alpha = this.finalBg.kirlihava.alpha - 0.13;
                this.finalBg.kirlitoprak.alpha = this.finalBg.kirlitoprak.alpha - 0.1;
                this.gunes.alpha = this.gunes.alpha + 0.16;
                var _loc_3:String = this;
                _loc_3.counter = this.counter++;
                this.pops.pop_pompa.visible = true;
                this.pops.bg.visible = true;
                this.pops.pop_pompa.popx.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.PopTicker);
                this.pops.pop_pompa.popx.buttonMode = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.sfxChannel.stop();
                this.sfxChannel = this.wrongChoice.play();
                this.pompa.x = 124.9;
                this.pompa.y = 405.8;
            }
```

When you work to turn these into a common function, you'll see how you need to optimize your variable design.

The key is probably arrays. Most variables should be in arrays. When you start putting your code into functions, you'll see why arrays work.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense since each "Icon" variable is represented by a MovieClip in the library. So each MC and corresponding variable should be assigned programmatically seperately.

Comment: You don't assign variables to everything. You only assign variables to things you need to reference in the code. You're positioning everything with code? Or do you use an editor like Animator? What software are you using?

Comment: @moot, he uses a swift decompiler, you can tell by look at variable names